# Rails 3.0 model Generation

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to generate model along with complete referential and integrity constraint from mysql database that has same constraints specified.The model should be automatically generated.

Comment: Can you please give more detail + context? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have huge database with many table along with pk-fk constraints.I wish not rewrite model for each table.I wish there to be application that using database schema generate model with same constraints so i query using active records.

Comment: Thanks for the info - please edit your question and 'flesh it out'. That way it is more likely to be a valuable question to other people who come along with the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Magic Model Generator is not available for rails 3.0 so you may try this out.
Create a Rails 2.2 app and use it with Magic Model Generator and then use the models in your Rails 3 app. [Link](http://github.com/drnic/magic_model_generator) for MMG

Comment: Isn't there other alternative than magic model or other software?

Comment: I dont have an idea about other gems.